# C++ Printing All Values in a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, nodes, traversal

So I have created a binary search tree that is stored within an array. This binary search tree (BST) stores a user input ID, Age, and Name, then places it within the array sorted in ascending order by the ID.

I am attempting to write a function report that loops through the array, printing each nodes' ID, age, name, and level that they would be at if represented as a binary tree.

For example, if I had these particular nodes

101 10 Bob

102 11 Steve

104 14 Walt

103 12 Lan

105 14 Bill

It would bring them as 
101 10 Bob 0, 1

02 11 Steve 1, 1

03 12 Lan 1,

104 13 Walt 2 ,

105 14 Bill 2 ,

However, for some reason, when attempting to print this particular example using my report function, I get strange negative numbers and a great deal of additional nodes that weren't previously inserted.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I no longer initialize the BST array size to 30, however, now report is no longer printing anything. I am a beginner, so my understanding of C++ is fairly minimal.

Here is my code.

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int count = 0;

struct Node
{
    int ID;
    int age;
    string name;

    Node()
    {

    }

    Node(int id, int Age, string nm)
    {
        this->ID = id;
        this->age = Age;
        this->name = nm;
    }
};

vector<Node> binaryTree;


BST::BST()
{

}



void BST::start()
{
    int choice;


    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Add a node to the tree" << endl;
    cout << "2. Delete a node from the tree" << endl;
    cout << "3. Find a node in the tree" << endl;
    cout << "4. Report the contents of the tree" << endl;
    cout << "5. Exit program" << endl;

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        insert();
    }

    if (choice == 3)
    {
        find();
    }

    if (choice == 4)
    {
        report();
    }


}

void BST::insert()
{

    int ID;
    int AGE;
    string NAME;
    cout << "Please enter the ID number, age and name" << endl;
    cin >> ID >> AGE >> NAME;

    Node *tree = new Node(ID, AGE, NAME);

    if (count == 0)
    {
        binaryTree.push_back(*tree);
        count++;
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        if ((binaryTree.at(count - 1).ID) < ID)
        {
            binaryTree.push_back(*tree);
            count++;
        }
    }


    if (count > 0)
    {
        if ((binaryTree.at(count - 1).ID) > ID)
        {
            Node *temp = new Node();
            *temp = binaryTree.at(count - 1);
            binaryTree.at(count - 1) = *tree;

            binaryTree.at(count) = *temp;
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Added! Size: " << binaryTree.size() << endl;

    start();


}


void BST::Delete()
{

}


void BST::find()
{
    int key;
    bool found = 0;

    cout << "What's the ID?" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;

    cin >> key;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < binaryTree.size(); i++)
    {
        if (binaryTree.at(i).ID == key)
        {
            cout << "The ID is " << binaryTree.at(i).ID << endl;
            cout << "The age ID " << binaryTree.at(i).age << endl;
            cout << "The name is " <<binaryTree.at(i).name << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;

            found = true;

        }
        if (found == false)
        {
            cout << "Not found." << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    start();
}


void BST::report()
{
    cout << "The contents of the tree are" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < binaryTree.size(); i++)
    {
        int level = 0;
        if (i == 0) level = 0;
        if (i == 2 || i == 3) level = 1;
        if (i >= 4 && i <= 7) level = 2;
        if (i >= 8 && i <= 15) level = 3;
        cout << binaryTree.at(i).ID << " " << binaryTree.at(i).age << " " << binaryTree.at(i).name << " " << level << endl;

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `binaryTree` vector is constructed with 30 elements. How many of them do you use? Subtract that number from 30 and you'll get the number of times you see "strange negative values". Maybe...

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. It should be one file and not require user input. Odds are that you will find the mistake yourself.

Comment: @user2618142 How is this creating an issue, if I may ask?

Comment: @DeiDei Fixed it, but now the issue of it not printing anything arises.

Answer (score 0):

A great deal of problems with this code.

int count was initialized in the header.
Removed that and initialized it in .cpp to get "count is ambiguous" error.

This is primarily due to

```
using namespace std;
```

Since count is a item within that namespace.